# How to bind first 100 records returning by a stored procedure using OPTION FAST and in background it will take remaining data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to bind thousands of records in the front end using a stored procedure in SQL Server and C#.

When I am executing the SP in SQL Server then it is returning 100 records very quickly and then selecting remaining records.

So can I bind those first 100 records in the front end so that the user doesn't have to wait for long and in the background it will fill remaining data in GridView?

Right now the user has to wait for so long and only once it has loaded all the records will the user be able to see this.

So can you please let me know how I can bind the first 100 records in the front end?

Comment: That isn't how it works. Sql server does not stream rows back to the client like that. If you have thousands of rows why not do some server side paging instead? That is what paging is used for.

Comment: What framework are you using? Asp.Net MVC? Web Forms? Are you using SignalR?

Comment: Why are you sending a lot of data to front-end? Maybe you're wasting a lot of data transfer. Think about it.

You should use paging on server side and send only what you really need.

Comment: @Ricardo França: it is web form. and i have to display all data in grid, it is needed by client.

Comment: Ok. So you can send two requests. The first one is to retreive the 100 and another to return all the stuff. Are you using Ajax (jQuery or ajax control toolkit)?

Comment: @Ricardo França: thanks for your response. I am using Ajax request but i dont have much idea that how can i merge both records from backend? how can i manage 2 requests output data ?

Comment: It's been a long time that I saw a web form code, but the idea is to merge on client-side. Are your grid render on server side?

Comment: I am binding a datatable using javascript and Ajx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116826/discussion-between-ricardo-franca-and-hp1104).

Comment: Have you considered using row.add to add subsequent rows? https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add() You will at least need to post your code or no one will be able to assist.

Answer (score -1):

- Use paging, enable paging and set page size to 100 so it will show only 100 rows of data when user click on second page it will display other 100 and so on
- You can also use `limit` in stored procedure set `limit = 100`

  ```
  SELECT * FROM TABLENAME LIMIT=100
  ```